# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Controllers and Views + static files in separate Class Library

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to create dashboard for my ASP Core 2 WebAPI and install it like nuget. So I have created a .NET Standard 2 class library and added some controllers, views.

When referencing that class lib and running my WebAPI, I'm able to reach that controller and it shows views (I followed this guide ["Sharing Controllers and Views in ASP.NET Core"](http://jackhiston.com/2017/8/15/sharing-controllers-and-views-in-aspnet-core/)). But when i packaging that class lib into nuget package, and installing it on WebAPI after navigating to dashboard controller, it says that views not found.

PS: I know about razor class lib, but if i not mistake it requires core 2.1 which is not available in my production server (and in some reasons it cant be upgraded xD)

Comment: Have you checked that adding the class library reference directly does not cause this issue?

Comment: Hi Moshin, thx for reply. When i adding class lib ref, it's work fine.